# Symfony Sonata-CacheBundle configuration error

Tags: php, symfony

I have Symfony CMF (se1.1) installed with Corebundle, Blockbundle & Adminbundle all working without errors. Now I installed Sonata Cachebundle (needed for Sonata Pagebundle) and the site now shows this error:

**InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "symfony" under "sonata_cache.caches"**

(I used Composer to install this bundle.)

Here a list of my configuration files regarding the Cachebundle;

**app/AppKernel.php**:

```
new Sonata\CacheBundle\SonataCacheBundle(),
```

**app/autoload.php**

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/**
* @var ClassLoader $loader
*/
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Sonata', __DIR__);

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
sonata_cache:
  caches:
  esi:
      token: an unique security key # a random one is generated by default
      servers:
          - varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:2000 {{ COMMAND }} "{{ EXPRESSION }}"

  ssi:
      token: an unique security key # a random one is generated by default

  mongo:
      database:   cache
      collection: cache
      servers:
          - {host: 127.0.0.1, port: 27017, user: username, password: pASS'}
          - {host: 127.0.0.2}

  memcached:
      prefix: test     # prefix to ensure there is no clash between instances
      servers:
          - {host: 127.0.0.1, port: 11211, weight: 0}

  predis:
      servers:
          - {host: 127.0.0.1, port: 6379, database: 42}

  apc:
      token:  s3cur3   # token used to clear the related cache
      prefix: test     # prefix to ensure there is no clash between instances
      servers:
          - { domain: kooqit.local, ip: 127.0.0.1, port: 80}

  symfony:
      token: s3cur3 # token used to clear the related cache
      php_cache_enabled: true # Optional (default: false), clear APC or PHP OPcache
      types: [mytype1, mycustomtype2] # Optional, you can restrict allowed cache types
      servers:
          - { domain: kooqit.local, ip: 127.0.0.1, port: 80}
```

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
sonata_cache_cache:
  resource: '@SonataCacheBundle/Resources/config/routing/cache.xml'
  prefix: /
```

I hope someone can point out what exactly is going wrong here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer is actually pretty simple (that's always the case when looking back).

In the app/config/config.yml file it is (obviously) not allowed to have 'options' wich are not  properly configured in Symfony CMF.

An option like 'mongo' will produce an error message if this function is not properly installed and configured in Symfony CMF (sounds logical).

So, my advice (credits to @ReynierPM) is to indeed comment out those sections that give an error. But beware that if you later on will use the full 'mongo' functionality, you have to uncomment that specific section to activate cache for it.

Comment: Glad you fix the issue, will you accept my answer or accept yours?

Comment: As my answer is based on your answer, the choice is a bit difficult. From a learning point of view for other users I will choose my answer as it contains more explanation. But as clearly stated in my answer, the credit goes to you as it is based on your answer..

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration have some errors: indent before `caches` and others should be four spaces, working example:

```
  sonata_cache:
      caches:
        esi:
            token: an unique security key # a random one is generated by default
            servers:
                - varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:2000 {{ COMMAND }} "{{ EXPRESSION }}"

        ssi:
            token: an unique security key # a random one is generated by default

        mongo:
            database:   cache
            collection: cache
            servers:
                - {host: 127.0.0.1, port: 27017, user: username, password: pASS'}
                - {host: 127.0.0.2}

        memcached:
            prefix: test     # prefix to ensure there is no clash between instances
            servers:
                - {host: 127.0.0.1, port: 11211, weight: 0}

        predis:
            servers:
                - {host: 127.0.0.1, port: 6379, database: 42}

        apc:
            token:  s3cur3   # token used to clear the related cache
            prefix: test     # prefix to ensure there is no clash between instances
            servers:
                - { domain: kooqit.local, ip: 127.0.0.1, port: 80}

        symfony:
            token: s3cur3 # token used to clear the related cache
            php_cache_enabled: true # Optional (default: false), clear APC or PHP OPcache
            types: [mytype1, mycustomtype2] # Optional, you can restrict allowed cache types
            servers:
                - { domain: kooqit.local, ip: 127.0.0.1, port: 80}
```

Try it!!! And of course as always run the commands `cache:clear` and `cache:warmup`

Comment: Cache:clear returns with --> {Unrecognized options "esi, ssi, mongo, memcached, predis, apc, symfony" under "sonata_cache"}

Comment: Sorry, my bad I made a mistake indenting the code, I fixed and when you have problems like that try deleting the cache by hand

Comment: Indetation fixed, but back to same error message --> {Unrecognized options "symfony" under "sonata_cache.caches"}

Comment: Try commenting that lines, I don't know what those are so I don't use at all

Comment: I commented out: ' symfony', then 'apc'. then 'predis, then 'memcached', then 'mongo'. After all these the errors are gone... (*tired*)